# Matrix of pages with internal alignment options

Tags: minipage

For multiple times now, I have wanted to make a matrix of pages where I can ask LaTeX to align analogous content elements across 'matrix entries'. This may not make much sense, so here is an example:

[image: An example of such a minipage matrix]
As you can see each page is in essence a list of content elements (here, first a text, then a align equation, then a single line, another align equation and so on.) However, I want analogous content elements to be alignable both horizontally and vertically. What analogous means is ideally determined by me as opposed to the computer, but if that is not possible then so be it.

Ideally, we would have some kind of environment to make the matrix and then fill it with pages afterwards. This would help with finding back a certain content element in the code if one wants to change it. Such an ideal system would also have ways to specify that alignment needs to happen, in a similar way to how the `align` environment uses the `&` functionality.

Alas, I haven't found such an environment, but there are ways to create this kind of matrix that are a bit more involved.

If you have any other tips and tricks, then these would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options one could try, mainly

- *Just using `\hspace` and `\vspace`.* Involves a lot of fiddling. You don't want to do this. Period.
- *Using Tabulars.* This doesn't always give satisfactory results. Alignment within a cell is not always great, especially if you want to specify alignment both horizontally and vertically. Tabulars also don't allow multiple lines of text or "unorthodox" content such as `align` equations. On top of this, because of the way the syntax works, you can quickly lose track of what in your page is where in your table.
- *Using repeated minipages.* In my opinion this is the best way to do it. It still has it's problems with vertical alignment, but there are sometimes tricks around this that I will share below.

**How to build a matrix of pages using the repeated minipage technique.**
Below is a picture of the result. The code for it can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FkpNW3_adaNary1RzT-tgP506Gzjcf4TQ3wqFJrdEcU/edit?usp=sharing), since it is a bit long.
[image: Result of this technique]

The basic idea is to use multiple minipages to create the matrix.

1. The width of each minipage will determine the width of the columns, and (compared to the textwidth of the page) the amount of columns.
2. The amount of minipages you add determines how many rows you have, since LaTeX will keep filling lines of pages until none are left in your code.
3. If you want the matrix to be wider than the textwidth of your page, then consider embedding all your pages in a signle outer page that you position using `\hspace` and `\vspace`. You would then give this outer page a width bigger than  `\textwidth` to give the space necessary to the inner pages.
4. Consider using standalone files for your separate inner pages. In this way, the matrix itself manifests as just the outer page, and references to the inner pages, combined with all the positioning and layout of the matrix as a whole. All the content within the pages is kept in separate files that are much easier to find and change.

An example for all of this is given in the code above.

Some general tricks and facts to know:

1. It is very important that each of your minipages has the same vertical size. As you can see in an example in the code document, minipages seem to align at their bottoms if they are not equally long.
2. As long as what you are doing is pretty tame, and all elements across columns have the same size, the columns will automatically be of equal length and you won't see the problem.
3. However, if all elements don't have the same size -- say you have a 2-row matrix in one column and a 4-row matrix in another -- then you will have to somehow equalize the length again by adding extra space.
4. There is no easy way to do this, but in good circumstances there are some easy solutions. Adding `\strut` ensures that your content element will be at least one textline high. In other cases, you can simply add a custom-sized strut by using `\vphantom{item from which you want its height.}`. I used this to make a 3-row matrix the same size as a 4-row matrix.
5. In any other cases, it is about mucking around with `\vspace{length}`, which can add vertical space in your document. For example, to shift something upwards without messing up any other alignment, you remove above and add below the same vertical space, even though this might not always have the desired effect. It isn't always a streamlined experience, but then again this method isn't perfect.
6. One way to check if the line-out actually worked is by adding lot's of `\hrulefill`'s in your document. This creates horizontal lines and can be seen in the example image above.